# Optimal way to maximaze so clan1 wins

Tags: c++, max

There are 2 clans, clan1 and clan2.We have been given powers of those 2 clans warriors in arrays in form of 2 arrays like P1,P2,...,PN and C1,C2,.....,CN.We want clan1 to win the war.What is the  maximum number of fights Team Clan1 can win when its warriors are arranged optimally or fight in an optimal order.
    like:
    no. of warriors = 10,
    powers of 1- 1,2,3,4,5
    powers of second- 0,1,3,2,6

```
so max wins clan1 can win = 4.
```

what is problem in my code

```
#no.of warriors n
int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
#powers of warriors
 int *p1 = new int(n);
 int *p2 = new int(n);
 for(int i=0 ; i<n;i++){
   scanf("%d",&p1[i]);
 }
 for(int i=0 ; i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d",&p2[i]);
 }

 selectionSort(p1,n);
 selectionSort(p2,n);

 int i=0 , j=0,sum=0;
 while(i<n&&j<n){
     while(p1[i]<=p2[j]){
         j++;
     }
     sum++;
     i++;
 }
printf("%d", sum);
```

constraints;

```
no.of warriors <=100000
power<= LLONG_MAX
```

Comment: You can see some of the problems [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8y98zt).

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your code.

- You use `selectionSort` but it's not defined. You can use `std::sort` from `algorithm`
- You dynamically allocate memory but you don't clean up. This can lead to a memory leak. You can use `std::vector` to avoid this problem.
- The inner while loop can go out of bounds. You should check the bounds
- The logic wasn't correct (or at least I wasn't able to fix it). I inverted the logic of the inner while loop.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::scanf("%d", &n);

    std::vector<int> clan1(n);
    for(auto &warrior : clan1){
        std::scanf("%d", &warrior);
    }
    std::vector<int> clan2(n);
    for(auto &warrior : clan2){
        std::scanf("%d", &warrior);
    }

    std::sort(std::begin(clan1), std::end(clan1));
    std::sort(std::begin(clan2), std::end(clan2));

    int i = 0, j = 0, sum = 0;
    while(i < n && j < n) {
        while(j < n && i < n && clan1[i] > clan2[j]) {
            i++;
            j++;
            sum++;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    std::printf("%d", sum);
}
```